# Gradle: Understand how unwanted dependency is picked up

Tags: java, gradle

In my module, I have a direct dependency on `com.my.org.common:es-library:1.4` which internally depends upon `org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.6.7` (according to the pom of that project).

I expected my module to choose `org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.6.7` but somehow it is choosing
`org.elasticsearch.client:transport:6.4.3`.

Checked entire dependency tree to confirm that there is no other dependency that pulls in `org.elasticsearch.client:transport`.

dependencyInsight command gives the same details as shown in below.

```
$gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.elasticsearch.client:transport
```

```
org.elasticsearch.client:transport:6.4.3 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 8
   ]

org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.6.7 -> 6.4.3
\--- com.my.org.common:es-library:1.4
     \--- compileClasspath
```

Why Gradle is pulling in 6.4.3 version of the dependency and how can I know where is that coming from?

Comment: It seems that [selected by rule](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#understanding_selection_reasons) refers to some customization in your corporate build environment.

Comment: @jaco0646 sorry for the late response. What you are saying seems right, but how can I confirm that or see where is that configured?

Comment: You could look at the Gradle plugins added to your build environment, for anything custom built by your corporation; but it might be easier to ask the operations team or whoever manages the builds.